# playground.xcworkspace couldn't be saved because a file already exists

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been learning Swift in my spare time, and I am new to iOS development. I have been reading a book from Big Nerd Ranch that teaches me the basics of Swift programming. I have one directory for the book. For each chapter, I start a new Playground or Project, as each chapter recommends. The book recommends to create Playgrounds and Projects using MacOS (versus iOS or tvOS). Every so often, I am getting the following error:

> The file "playground.xcworkspace" couldn't be saved in the folder "chxx-foo.playground" because a file with the same name already exists
>
> To save the file, either provide a different name, or move aside or delete the existing file, and try again.

When I look into the directory for the playground, I always see only one playground.xcworkspace. The error seems innocuous, so I am not too concerned, just wondering if my development environment could be tweaked differently to avoid this message, or maybe I am doing something that is not idiomatic to iOS development.

How can I get rid of the error message that keeps coming up?

Comment: Are you using saving your projects in a folder that using iCloud or iCloud documents?

Comment: I've seen this, it's just a glitch with Xcode.  Xcode is trying to save the playground while a save or something else is already in progress.  Just ignore them and carry on.

Comment: @JAL you can store Xcode projects in iCloud drive or on the Desktop that gets synced using iCloud (as of Sierra)

Comment: @der_michael Ah, I see what you are saying now.  Didn't think of that, only because I've seen this error when saving locally (and I haven't updated to Sierra yet)

Comment: @der_michael I am not using iCloud to save my documents. It is stored on my local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to go into the directory through Finder and rename it. It will generate a new one of the same name as the one you just renamed. After that, delete the one you just named, leaving the one it generated after you renamed it. Do this in a new Playground to test to make sure it works; however, it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that when it comes up next.

Comment: Let me know if this does not work, I will test again if not and update it accordingly. For me, my answer works.